# Go back to the original entry point after executing the instructions in the newly added segment- PE32+, C++

Tags: c++, x86-64, assembly

I am learning `PE32+` (64 bit) files. I have added a new section to the `PE32+` file and made the new section as the entry point. Some simple instructions are added in the new segment. Now I want to go to the old entry point after executing the new segment, then continue execution from there. I read the articles for `PE32` that are using `assembly` language instructions. But I am not able get it working for `64 bit`(tried to add `.asm` files). Please help me with any useful information. Is it possible to do it in `C++`?